# Are there keyboard shortcuts for the Safari debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

Firebug and eclipse both let me step through code using function keys. Does Safari have equivalent capabilities?

Comment: What shortcut is used to go to a specific line in Debugger section of Safari (e.g. I want to navigate instantly to a specific line in .js file)? Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The Scripts Debugger was updated to support some popular keyboard shortcuts:

- Continue — <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> on other platforms.
- Step Over — <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>’</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>’</kbd> on other platforms.
- Step Into — <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> on other platforms.
- Step Out — <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> on other platforms.
- Next Call Frame — <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> on all platforms.
- Previous Call Frame — <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> on all platforms.
- Evaluate Selection When on a Breakpoint — <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> on other platforms.

Credit goes to: http://webkit.org/blog/829/web-inspector-updates/

Comment: +1 those `<kbd>` tags are a menace. Why don't they work in comments?? Also, it's pretty neat how F8 on my Mac is the Play/Pause media button.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F1</kbd> in the Web Inspector shows a help screen with all the keys. (Safari version 5.1.2)

Answer (score 3):

In my case is different, I'm using Safari 13 on macOS (Catalina)

- F6 - Step over
- F7 - Step into
- F8 - Step out

I found these from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use <kbd>⌃⌘Y</kbd> or <kbd>⌘\</kbd> to pause the Safari JS debugger when the Debugger tab is active.

[image: Tooltips are your friend :)]